# MATLAB built functions to c++

Tags: c++, c, function, matlab, built-in

Is it possible to know the code behind a built-in function in MATLAB so that it can be converted (manually or automatically) to C/C++? This is because I was using findpeaks with 'MinPeakProminence' in MATLAB but didn't know how to build a similar function in C++.

Comment: It’s proprietary, meaning that you can’t see the source code, and if you could, you’d be be stealing if you copied that code. However, you might be able to use MATLAB Coder to convert your MATLAB code to C++. Not all functions are supported, but `findpeaks` is.

Comment: MATLAB coder, never heard of it before

Comment: can I somehow use the MATLAB coder together with Arduino IDE?

Comment: @Khalid Yes you can. See [this link](https://de.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

Someone seems to have already done this, maybe they used the same methods as described in the matlab docs (or Coder)?

https://github.com/E24056679-NCKU/MATLAB-findpeaks-in-C-

Another possible place to look would be Octave's implementation -- not sure if it's built-in or a script.